# bridged LXC: container's mac address learned on wrong interface

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, bridge, lxc

Ubuntu host has **p2p1.17** physical interface attached to **bri17** bridge. LXC container *FOO* has following net config:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = bri17
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:aa:aa:66
```

When I start it, I get:

```
# lxc-info -n FOO | grep Link
Link:           vethHUPG1B

# brctl show bri17
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
bri17           8000.3cfdfe01eee0       no              p2p1.17
                                                        vethHUPG1B
```

so far it looks OK, but

```
# brctl showmacs bri17
port no mac addr                is local?       ageing timer
  1     00:16:3e:aa:aa:66       no                19.81
  2     fe:d8:27:6b:72:1d       yes                0.00
  2     fe:d8:27:6b:72:1d       yes                0.00
```

shows that the container's mac address is learned on wrong port (p2p1.17)

When I add ip's to the bri17 and container's eth0, they can ping themselves, but container can not ping anything outside host, like the gateway. To be more funny, container has correct arp table:

```
# arp -n
Address          HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
gateway-ip       ether   00:15:2c:16:68:40   C                     eth0
```

What is wrong in this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with driver/firmware of Intel X710 (p2p1) network adapter. Fixed by compiling newest drivers from Intel.